# Converting a char from Linux terminal to command

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I write a kernel module for my tty device to control them. I have everything done but I would like to add one functionality.
If I type "z" in terminal I want to read by terminal as echo "z" > dev/tty0 for example. Is that possible and how can I make it?

Comment: wait, you wrote a Kernel Driver and you don't know about stdin? Is it a popcorn kernel?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What does "I want to read by terminal as echo "z" > dev/tty0" mean?

Comment: If I type "z" in terminal, it will read "z" as echo "z" > dev/tty0.

Comment: Your structure is to normally hook the tty to a line discipline.  You can allow people to login on the 'tty' using an inittab and updating '/etc/securetty'.  Or you can manually run `sh` with "/dev/tty0" as stdin/stdout.  You need to arrange this in your boot up scripts.  Do you not expect to have user space programs or did you not know this is how it is traditionally done?  You definitely need to have some sort of rootfs w/o significantly altering the Linux kernel 'init' code.